# 64-bit java acting like 32-bit Java after installing Java 8 Update 20 - Weird

Tags: java, eclipse, version

I tried to install `Aptana Studio 3` on my laptop, but after installation, it gave me the error `"Could not load the JNI shared library ... "` when I tried to run it. A google search told me that it needed `32-bit Java` installation. Since my installation is 64-bit, I was sure it would not work. I did not try again. Just then a pop-up came that there was a new update of java available for my system, `Java 8 Update 20`. Previously I was on `Java 8 update 11`. I did the update and then a restart. After that, I tried running the Aptana Studio 3 once more, and to my surprise it was working perfectly.

But then I came onto a doubt and tried to run `Eclipse` (mine is 64-bit) and I was shown the problem `"Java was started and returned with exit code=13"`, which a google search told me that I was trying to run 64-bit eclipse on a 32-bit Java installation. So I did a `"java -version"` and it is now showing me I have a 32-bit Java installation.

All these happened in 10 minutes. I mean I was using Eclipse this morning before the update.

I never knew this could even happen. I regularly use Eclipse and I know I have a `64-bit Java` installed, and the PATH is also set correctly.

I have no idea what is going on, but I need my Eclipse to be up and running, I am in the middle of my android application project, and now I have no clue. Please help!

OS : Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1 64-bit

I am attaching two screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the first version of update 11 dominates your system and that's why you have got the 32bit version of last update. The best advice I can give is, update the Java version always manually (it seems the mechanism for 64bit updates does not work well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had installed both types of Java (32-bit and 64-bit) (Java 8 Update 11).

The Java version updated was only the 32-bit version (I cannot tell you why).

On start Java always uses the most current version which is 32-bit in your case.

Comment: Yes, now I see what you are trying to mean, but then I realized, I never installed a 32-bit version of Java.I have no clue how it got installed on my machine. Anyway, what should I do now? A fresh install of Java?

Comment: @SajibAcharya deinstalling java completely and reinstall the needed parts could solve the problem. I cannot guide you because I only und linux for java development and this has other problems ;)

Comment: You must have had it longer than today; possibly the auto-update of the 32 bits version you didn't know you had (which is the only version that actually auto-updates, the 64 bits version does not) caused the default-java settings to get switched around. What you should do is read Nishant's correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Modify `eclipse.ini` and set `vm` property to your preferred JVM:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe
```

This makes eclipse run on a JVM which is independent of what is specified by `JAVA_HOME` or `PATH`. See [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for more details.